# Frame in which Goal should be set

Tags: ros, transforms, stampedtransform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With respect to which frame, robot goal should be set - is it /odom or /base_link or /map ? Out of /odom , /map and /base_link frames which should be the source and target frames in listener.waitForTransform(...) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61948/frame-in-which-goal-should-be-set/) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A goal is usually set with respect to /base_link. When you give a 2d_nav_goal in rviz, the frame i.d is set to base link base_link (`goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "base_link"`).

We wait for transform is between /map and /base_link. It happens this way, the robot_pose_ekf node publishes the transform between /odom and /base_link and the /amcl node creates the /map frame, establishes a connection with /odom and in turn calculates the transform between /map and /base_link. So, when you set a goal on map frame, (it waits for transform between /map and /base_link), calculates the transform and publishes it on the /base_link frame.
[image: image description]
Read more [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl) and [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) for better understanding.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0